# kentico stats by user

Tags: analytics, kentico

How can I capture how many times an authenticated user has viewed a page in Kentico 7?
We are currently using the analytics in Kentico 7.
Example:

---

User  --   Page --   ViewCount
user1 --   News --   05
user2 --   News --   19
user4 --   News --   23

---

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytics do not track by user.  You can turn on Contact Activities if you have the EMS license and find out how many times a specific contact has performed a an activity you define (view page, download a file, etc.).  In v7 though, I'd be very careful about turning on Contacts and activity tracking as they are not optimized at all for performance.